# Cannot read an image from different path

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I would like to display a cropped image using the library [ImageCropper](https://github.com/INHack20/ImageCropper.Forms).

I have managed to crop the image with the following code :

```
async void OnchangePicture(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    new ImageCropper()
    {
    CropShape = ImageCropper.CropShapeType.Oval,
    Success = (imageFile) =>
    {
       

        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
        {
            ProfileImage.Source = ImageSource.FromResource(imageFile);

        });

        Console.WriteLine("Cropped File Path " + imageFile);
        Console.WriteLine("Photo Path " + result.FullPath);
    }
    }.Show(this, result.FullPath);
}
```

The ouput :

```
Cropped File Path /Users/xxxx/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/434F95FE-DF90-47C5-BB0E-A7C55E385CB0/data/Containers/Data/Application/18491607-7363-46CE-B9DD-F84C4C243170/Documents/aad2dc8b-4e9b-4f99-bb1e-cf91cbe8bbd7.jpg


Photo Path /Users/xxxx/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/434F95FE-DF90-47C5-BB0E-A7C55E385CB0/data/Containers/Data/Application/18491607-7363-46CE-B9DD-F84C4C243170/tmp/1350BF4E-CEA4-4E48-B312-3FE15B7B7C2F.jpeg
```

ProfileImage.Source is not displaying the image from the path **imageFile** and I do not know how to make it work. With the output console I have noticed that the path of imageFile is not in my Xamarin project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FromResource` is for files contained in the project's resources.  To load from a file path, use `FromFile`

```
ProfileImage.Source = ImageSource.FromFile(imageFile);
```